# Migrating database to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

As far as I know the key points to migrate an existing database to SQL Azure are:

1. Tables has to contain a clustered
   index. This is mandatory.
2. Schema and data migration should be
   done through data sync, bulk copy,
   or the [SQL Azure migration
   wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/), but not with the restore option in SSMS.
3. The .NET code should handle the
   [transient conditions related with
   SQL Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/28/best-practices-for-handling-transient-conditions-in-sql-azure-client-applications.aspx).
4. The creation of logins is in the
   `master` database.
5. Some TSQL features may be not
   supported.

And I think that's all, am I right? Am I missing any other consideration before starting a migration?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2015-08-06**

- The Web and Business editions are no longer available, they are replaced by Basic, Standard and Premium Tiers.
- [.CLR Stored Procedure Support is now available](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/401015-support-clr-stored-procedures)
- New: SQL Server support for Linked Server and Distributed Queries against Windows Azure SQL Database, [more info](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2012/09/19/announcing-updates-to-windows-azure-sql-database/).

Additional considerations:

- Basic tier allows 2 GB
- Standard tier allows 250 GB
- Premium tier allow 500 GB

The following features are NOT supported:

- Distributed Transactions, see [feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/584699-add-dtc-support-for-sql-azure) on UserVoice
- SQL Service broker, see [feature request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure) on UserVoice

Answer (score 2):

I'd add in bandwidth considerations (for initial population and on-going bandwidth). This has cost and performance considerations.

Another potential consideration is any long running processes or large transactions that could be subject to SQL Azure's rather cryptic throttling techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Another key area to point out are SQL Jobs.  Since SQL Agent is not running, SQL Jobs are not supported.

One way to migrate these jobs are to refactor so that a worker role can kick off these tasks.  The content of the job might be moved into a stored procedure to reduce re-architecture.  The worker role could then be designed to wake up and run at the appropriate time and kick off the stored procedure.

Comment: This article describes how Azure Automation can be used as an alternative solution for running SQL Jobs: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/